# How does the graphics pipeline use shared memory?

Tags: graphics, gpu, gpgpu, pipeline

In GPGPU algorithms, using shared or local memory is important to achieve high performance.
Since GPUs are made to run the graphics pipeline, the shared memory has to have some important use, but I can not figure out what.

Someone who has read the Intel graphics driver docs may have the answer to this.

Comment: One part of this great tutorial might help answer your question [A trip through the Graphics Pipeline 2011, part 13](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-13/)

Comment: I also found that resource, and it gives a great explanation of how shared memory works, but now how it is used.